# "There are 2 ways for A to do ... " or "There are 2 ways for A doing ..."?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to make this sentence,

> There are two ways for C++ calling C# Class Library.

I don't know if

> There are two ways for C++ to call C# Class Library.

would be better.

PS: I know it's a little bit technical, however, grammar is grammar, it's always the same with the common sentence.
[About C++ call C# Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2 is almost right.

> There are two ways for C++ to call a C# library.

or

> There are two ways for a C++ program to call a C# library.

<sub>*Why would you ever want to call a C# library from C++?!*</sub>

Comment: Because our application is a C++ program, but the third party dll is a C# library.